# When delete a child update the parent typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have subProjects and Positions, both of them are interfaces but subProjects have positionIds[ ] as array and when I add a new Position the id of position goes into positionIds[] .
The problem is when I delete a position the id of the position is still in the positionIds[ ] when I refresh the page is not there anymore.
How can when delete position automatically the subproject to be updated or something like this.
Can someone with splice make a solution ?
I am working with Angular 4, Typescript.
I used like this but when I delete a position others items are dissapear and not showing and when refresh the page are there, how can i make this with splice.

This is when I delete Position

```
deletePosition(position) {
const text = `Do you really want to delete  ${position.name}?`;
this.dialog.open(ConfirmationDialogComponent, { data: text, disableClose: true })
  .afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    if (result) { 
     const subIds = this.subproject.positionIds;
      subIds.splice(subIds.indexOf(position.id, 0));
      this.store.dispatch(new DeletePositionAction(position.id));
      console.log(position.id, '###');
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank's guys for showing my question and didn't answer, I found how to delete it.

```
const subIds = this.subproject.positionIds;
subIds.splice(subIds.indexOf(position.id), 1);
this.store.dispatch(new DeletePositionAction(position.id));
```